# Key bindings in zshrc do not take any effect

Tags: keyboard, terminal, zsh, ubuntu-11.10

I have just switched to [zsh](http://www.zsh.org/), and I would like to `bind` <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd> and <kbd>Delete</kbd> keys such that they would act similar to how they do in [bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/).

I have found some commands that work if I enter them directly into the command line:

```
bindkey '\eOF' end-of-line
bindkey '\e[3~' delete-char
bindkey '\eOH' beginning-of-line
```

Yet those commands do not take any effect when they're part of the `zshrc`.
Other `zshrc` commands work fine. *I do remember to restart terminal after each change*.

I'm using ubuntu 11.10.

Please help, I have tried to find a similar questions, yet I can't find any solution.

Comment: Solved by: bindkey '^[OH' beginning-of-line
bindkey '^[OF' end-of-line
bindkey '^[[3~' delete-char

Answer (score 1):

You could try the things from [here](http://zshwiki.org/home/zle/bindkeys)?

Also, have you tried putting the bindkey commands at the bottom of "$HOME/.zshrc" to ensure they are not being over-ridden?

Answer (score 0):

Comment by OP:

> Solved by:
>
> ```
> bindkey '^[OH' beginning-of-line
> bindkey '^[OF' end-of-line
> bindkey '^[[3~' delete-char
> ```